# Use of Distinct in jena sparql?

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena

I am trying to write a SPARQL query but not getting it right.  I want to get one answer of each type on `?x` and no duplicate value of `?x`

I thought `DISTINCT` keyword will do that but it doesn't on my data, here is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?x ?ax ?bx ?cx 
WHERE 
{ 
  ?a <SUB:> ?x .
  ?a <DATE:> ?ax .
  ?a <SENDERNAME:> ?bx .
  ?a <MESSAGEID:> ?cx. 
  ?a <REFERENCES:> ?z .
  FILTER regex(?z,'<','i')
} 
LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
```

The problem is I am still getting duplicate value of `?x`

How can I apply ditinct only on `?x`?

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` in SPARQL applies over rows not variables so it is perfectly valid to get duplicate values for one/more columns in a row provided that the row as a whole is distinct.

The typical way to achieve what you are after is to use the `GROUP BY` clause to group solutions by a specific variable - in your case `?x` - and then use the `SAMPLE()` aggregate to pull out sample values for the other columns you are interested in e.g.

```
SELECT ?x (SAMPLE(?ax) AS ?date) (SAMPLE(?bx) AS ?sender) (SAMPLE(?cx) AS ?messageID)
WHERE 
{ 
  ?a <SUB:> ?x .
  ?a <DATE:> ?ax .
  ?a <SENDERNAME:> ?bx .
  ?a <MESSAGEID:> ?cx. 
  ?a <REFERENCES:> ?z .
  FILTER regex(?z,'<','i')
}
GROUP BY ?x
LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
```

Now this may now give you what you are looking for because you haven't told us any details about your data or what the expected results should look like (doing so will substantially improve future questions you post)

What the above gives you is a row for each `?x` and then a randomly selected value for each of `?ax`, `?bx` and `?cx` taken from the rows that make up each group.

If what you are actually trying to do is to pull out the distinct subjects and then find the details of messages associated with that subject then you either have to use your existing query and do the grouping manually in code or you'll need to make two separate queries - one to get distinct subjects and a second for each distinct subject to get the messages associated with it.